# How to get listeners for a variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I know I can attach a listener to a variable like this:

```
$scope.$watch("variableName", listenerFunc);
```

I'm wondering whether it's possible to query a variable to find out which functions are already listening to it.

Specifically, I'd like to do something like the following

```
if( listenerIsNotAlreadyAssigned("variableName",listenerFunc) ){
    $scope.$watch("variableName", listenerFunc);     // assign it
}
```

Is there a way to implement the code above in Angular?  If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for the accept! I updated my first approach as a service with a demo and also added another approach.

Comment: Thanks the for the answer. It was a big help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method that might be considered hacky.. **[Demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AbAwObE/5/edit)**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {    
  function checkWatchString(prop) {
    var found = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.$$watchers, function(item, i) {
      if (item.exp === prop) { found = true; }
    });
    return found;
  }

  $scope.$watch('foo', function() {

  });

  console.log(checkWatchString('bar')); //false
  console.log(checkWatchString('foo')); //true;
});
```

If you store a reference to the creation of a watch, you get a function reference that cancels the watch. You could take the obvious approach and track this manually and also be keeping the cancel function for each watch available.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = '123';

  var reg = {};

  if (!reg.foo) {
    reg.foo = $scope.$watch('foo', function() {
      console.log('foo changed');
    });
  }
});
```

I made an demo using a service for this: **http://jsbin.com/AbAwObE/4/edit**

### Watch service

```
app.factory('watchService', function() {
  var watchService = function(prop, unset) {
    if (!watchService[prop]) {
      return false;
    }
    if (unset) {
      watchService[prop]();
      delete watchService[prop];
    }
    return true;
  };
  return watchService;
});
```

#### Add $watch

```
watchService[prop] = $scope.$watch(prop, function() {
  ++$scope.changeCount;
});
```

#### Check $watch

```
if (watchService(prop)) {
```

#### Remove $watch

```
watchService(prop, true);
```